# Sublime Text 3 keybinding priority

Tags: sublimetext3, key-bindings, keymapping

When I've installed a new sublime package the new package occasionally overwrites a keybinding I've added.

In my User sublime-keymap settings is there any way to give priority to my custom key-binding? For example any custom key-mapping I add has priority over default package ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Sublime Unofficial Docs](https://docs.sublimetext.io/guide/extensibility/packages.html#customizing-or-overriding-packages), packages (including any key bindings) are loaded in the following order:

1. `Packages/Default`;
2. shipped packages in lexicographical order;
3. installed packages in lexicographical order;
4. all remaining user packages, except for `Packages/User`, that did not override anything, in lexicographical order;
5. `Packages/User`

Basically, any settings you have in `Packages/User` are the final word in what happens. So, if an installed plugin tries to use a keybinding for which you already have a definition in `Packages/User`, it won't work – your settings will override it.

Comment: Thanks. I thought my Packages/User were being overwrote. It turned out to be a separate error, but thanks to the info you shared I knew that being overwritten wasn't the issue. So thanks for the help!